# Картинка с текстом не встают рядом, а друг под другом

Tags: html, css

Верстаю header и проблема в том, что в классе header картинка и текст встают друг под другом, а надо, чтобы картинка прижималась к левому краю, а текст к правому краю.

Вот код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="rus">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Bank</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header"> <div><img src="logo.jpg" class="logo"></div><div class="numbers"> 8-800-900-00-00 </br>+7(3452)523000</p></div></div>
        <div class="header2">
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

код css

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    background: #ffffff;
}
.wrapper {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    min-width:1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
    display: table-row;
    min-width:1000px;
    height: 10%;
    border: 1 px solid;
}

.header2 {
    display: table-row;
    height: 10%;
    min-width:1000px;
}

.logo{
    display: table-column;
}

.numbers {
    display: table-column;
    margin-left;100px;
    color: #eb5017;
    font-size: 20pt;
}
```

Comment: Используйте flex

Comment: не подскажете как это сделать

Answer (score 1):

Ваш пример использовать не стал, но использую ту же структуру блока с картинкой и текстом 
Вот вам пример:

p.s Нажмите на кнопку "Выполнить код"

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://icon-library.net/images/icon-code/icon-code-4.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="numbers">
    <a href="#">8 123 456-78-90</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">8 123 456-78-90</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вот [ТУТ](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) очень красивый и информативный гайд по флексам, советую к прочтению